# Ldap query to get the ACL

Tags: active-directory, ldap, acl, ldap-query

Is there a way to get the ACL of an objects in Active Directory by using LDAP query? I looked through but couldn't find anything relevant that would give an example to get the ACL of an object.

I saw a [query posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167981/list-acls-using-ldap-query) but there were no answers. I am trying to get data like the following example where all the permssions can the principal can be seen -

[image]

Any examples or documentation to show how this can be retrieved would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The permissions for any object are held in an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-ntsecuritydescriptor) called `nTSecurityDescriptor`. This is a binary attribute, which requires further interpretation, possibly with a programming language better than shell.

The tricky thing is that unless you bind to AD as an administrator, you will not be authorized to get System ACL (SACL) part of a security descriptor and therefore the domain controller will not return the descriptor at all. You may however include additional [search control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/3888c2b7-35b9-45b7-afeb-b772aa932dd0) to indicate that you are only interested in other parts of security descriptor (owner, group and/or DACL). The permissions you see in the window are the part of DACL.

Example for ldapsearch:

```
$ ldapsearch -Q -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -h addc.domain.local -b "dc=domain,dc=
local" -E '!1.2.840.113556.1.4.801=::MAMCAQc=' "sAMAccountName=Domain Admins" nTSecurityDescriptor

dn: CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local
nTSecurityDescriptor:: AQAEnHQWAACQFgAAAAAAABQAAAAEAGAWawAAAAUKSAAHAAAAAwAAAAHJdcnqbG9LgxnWf0VElQYUzChINxS8RZsHrW8BXl8oAQUAAAAAAAUVAAAA/XexVgt12XaDPStG3BcAAAUKSAAHAAAAAwAAAAHJdcnqbG9LgxnWf0VE...
```

This uses `-E` switch to use additional search control with value of `MAMCAQc=`, which is a base64-encoded BER-encoded value of ASN.1 structure with flags value of 7 (meaning to get owner, group and DACL information - all except SACL):

```
$ printf "\x30\x03\x02\x01\x07" | base64
MAMCAQc=
```

If you are interested in DACL only, you may use the value of 4, i.e.:

```
$ printf "\x30\x03\x02\x01\x04" | base64
MAMCAQQ=
```

Parsing the security descriptor value is quite complex and I would recommend to use some library, i.e. https://github.com/Tirasa/ADSDDL for Java implementation.